# editing a dataframe in R invoking vi

Tags: r

I am trying to edit a dataframe, content and titles from R.

there is a command edit(), but you can also invoke a vi editor by using vi([data.frame]).

You can view it and edit, it, but it saves the file to a file that I don't seem able to access and turn into a new edited data.frame.

example:

```
data(Orange)
test <- vi(Orange)
```

you should bring up a vi editor, and can change things here.  if you save it, it creates a separate file in some temp directory.  When you go back to R, and look at test, you'll see that none of your changes are in there.

Anyone know how to invoke a vi editor on the data.frame, such that the changes will be saved to a new data.frame?

Comment: I think you wanted `<- edit(...,editor = "vi")` rather than just `<- vi(...)`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you save the file in vi? Can you reproduce the problem with other editors?

Comment: @exl: your call should look like test <- vi(Orange, file = <your file>), but Vincent is right, should work without specifying file and it does work for me too.

Comment: thanks everyone.  I forgot to mention an important thing.  I'm using OSX, the gui on R.  I think that the help files indicate that the argument for editor is ignored, and only the document editor is used.  however, when I use test <- vi(Orange), it brings up MacVim window, where I can edit, then save, then close.  However, when I look at test, it is still the original Orange data.frame

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to this *awesome* function!

Answer (score 1):

I am running the same setup: `OSX` and `R` 3.0.1 and don't have an issue -- perhaps you're missing the saving step?

```
data(Orange)
test <- vi(Orange)
```

Then i edit the first data point, and hit the red button -- which opens a dialog box to save. You can also select save by hitting `Command-S` or selecting it from the menu.

[image]

This will not alter `Orange`, but it will pass the altered `Orange` to test.

Comment: Thanks for the demo.  I am also using  R 3.0.1 and OSX 10.7.5. Yeah, I thought this should work for me as well, but it doesn't seem to. When I use test <- vi(Orange), it brings it up in MacVim.  I save it using :w to save.  It saves to a strange temp directory (/private/var/folders/q0/mfycdv3n4z97d0c4gdds01s40000gn//T/Rtmp7d8lu9/), and gives it an temp file name with an .R extension.  Then I close the window.  Back in R, test is identical to Orange.  When you did this, was there a separate temp file saves in a similar manner?  thanks!

Comment: Have you tried saving and quitting using `:wq` rather than the close button, or does that not work in macvim?